# If $A=\{(x,y)\mid\exists t>0 , (x,y)=(t,\sin(\frac{1}{t}))\}$ and $U$ is an open set, then $U\cap A \neq \varnothing $?

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $A=\left \{ (x,y)\mid\exists t>0 , (x,y)=(t,\sin(\frac{1}{t})) \right \}$ and let 
>   $b\in [-1;1]$. Show that if $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(0,b)\in U$, then $U\cap A \neq \varnothing $

I have a somewhat intuitive understanding of this, but have great struggle to write something rigorous about this.

I started of by noting that is $U$ is an open set, and $(0,b)\in U$ then $\exists r >0$ such that $B((0,b),r)\subset U$. Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x\in B((0,b),r)$, then $x\in U$.

We also know a few trigonomic properties, mostly:

- $\sin(x) \approx x$ when $x \rightarrow 0$
- $\sin(1/x)$ takes infinitely many values in $[-1,1]$ when $x \rightarrow 0$

So now, if $x\in B((0,b),r))$, then it can be small enough so that $x$ is close to $0$ and since $\sin(1/x)$ takes all the values from $[-1,1]$. And here my thoughts stop. I don't know what else to write. I seem to have the intuitive understanding of this, but just can't write anything on paper.

Comment: Perhaps it helps if you focus on the fact that the set $[0,r) \times \{b\}$ is contained in $U$. With the smaller target, it may be easier to see what you want to aim at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b\in [-1,1].$ For  $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $\{x^{-1}: x\in [1/2\pi (n+1), 1/2\pi n]\}=[2\pi n,2\pi (n+1)].$

So there exists $x_n\in  [1/2\pi (n+1),1/2\pi n]$ such that $\sin (1/x_n)=b. $ That is,  $(x_n,b)=(x_n,\sin (1/x_n))\in A.$ And the distance from $(0,b)$ to $(x_n,b)$ is $x_n,$ which is less than $1/ n.$

A nbhd $U$  of $(0,b)$  contains every point whose distance to ($0,b)$ is less than $1/n,$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$.  So $U$ contains $(x_n,b)$ for some $n,$ and $(x_n,b)\in A.$

Answer (score 1):

You know that given $b \in [-1, 1]$ and an open set $U$ such that $(0,b) \in U$, there exists a $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the line segment $([0, t_0], b) \subset U$.

Now, find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < t_0$. Then what do you know about the set of values in $A$ between the $x$ values of $\frac{1}{N + 2 \pi}$ and $\frac{1}{N}$?

Comment: How come we can state that it contains a line segment without knowing whether it is convex or not?

Comment: Open sets can be defined by any point having some open ball centered on that point contained in the set. The ball will also contain the line segment. No need to worry about convexity

Comment: Well I can take N that is bigger than $\frac{1}{t_0}$,  but as for your question, I don't know what to answer. Is it concerning x as for sin(x) or something else?

Comment: You know that $\sin(x)$ where $N < x < N + 2\pi$ maps onto the region $[-1, 1]$  since $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic.  Therefore $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ where $\frac{1}{N+2\pi} < x < \frac{1}{N}$ maps onto $[-1, 1]$ too since the map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ maps $[\frac{1}{N + 2\pi}, \frac{1}{N}]$ onto $[N, N+2\pi]$

Comment: That is to say, there is an $x_0 \in [\frac{1}{N+2\pi}, \frac{1}{N}]$ such that $(x_0, \sin(\frac{1}{x_0})) = (x_0, b)$ which is in the line segment $([0, t_0], b) \subset U$